# Is co-design applicable to branding projects?

Tags: workflow, client-relations, designers, branding, design-process

I've been reading up on co-design / human-centred design (whatever you want to call) it recently.

It seems like a great approach to take when working on, for example, large web or app projects as it would give a good sense of what is required in terms of usability and functionality (e.g. by interviewing potential users of the system).

But what about other types of projects? If you're designing a new logo for a company... would it help to be interviewing your client's customers? or would it be better to scale things down and just interview a few members of the company?

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to think about the reason for human-centered design when considering this